# LINQ to replace foreach in Table creation

Tags: c#, linq

I need to create a Table (LINQ to replace foreach in TableRow creation) by adding rows corresponding to objects in a generic list. We can do it as listed below using a foreach loop. How can we achieve this functionality using **LINQ** without foreach?

Note: One table cell need to be added corresponding to each property in the object.

```
 System.Web.UI.WebControls.Table tableControl = new Table();

 foreach (FinancialTransaction transaction in transactionsList)
        {
            TableRow row = new TableRow();

            TableCell cellLineNumber = new TableCell();
            cellLineNumber.Text = Convert.ToString(transaction.Line);
            row.Cells.Add(cellLineNumber);

            TableCell cellEmpID = new TableCell();
            cellEmpID.Text = Convert.ToString(transaction.EmpID);
            row.Cells.Add(cellEmpID);

            TableCell cellSSN = new TableCell();
            cellSSN.Text = transaction.SSN;
            row.Cells.Add(cellSSN);

            tableControl.Rows.Add(row);
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ForEach` LINQ if `transactionsList` is `List`, but you could improve readability a little bit:

```
transactionsList.ForEach(transaction => {
     TableRow row = new TableRow();

     valueList = new object[] { 
                                  transaction.Line, 
                                  transaction.EmpID, 
                                  transaction.SSN 
                              };

     row.Cells.AddRange(valueList.Select(value => CreateCell(value))
                            .ToArray());

});

private TableCell CreateCell(object cellText)
{
    TableCell cell = new TableCell();
    cell.Text = Convert.ToString(cellText);

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `Aggregate`:

```
var tableControl = transactionsList.Aggregate(new Table(), (acc, transaction) => 
{  
    TableRow row = new TableRow();

    TableCell cellLineNumber = new TableCell();
    cellLineNumber.Text = Convert.ToString(transaction.Line);
    row.Cells.Add(cellLineNumber);

    TableCell cellEmpID = new TableCell();
    cellEmpID.Text = Convert.ToString(transaction.EmpID);
    row.Cells.Add(cellEmpID);

    TableCell cellSSN = new TableCell();
    cellSSN.Text = transaction.SSN;
    row.Cells.Add(cellSSN);

    acc.Rows.Add(row);

    return acc;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

How about the foreach of Linq itself?
or check [this](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ie=UTF-8&ion=1#hl=nl&gs_nf=1&tok=t1yb1lT88GN-16_Rb5l_Rw&cp=17&gs_id=n&xhr=t&q=linq%20alternative%20foreach&pf=p&newwindow=1&safe=off&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&oq=linq%20alternative%20&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=6b517538c876e673&biw=1280&bih=939&ion=1) link

It is also possible to create your own [Extension Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx)